# Hackerrank: Sherlock and Anagrams

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap, substring, anagram

Problem description: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sherlock-and-anagrams

Adding a snapshot of the problem statement:
[image]

I am getting only few test cases correct. My algorithm is:

1. Find all substrings of given string.

   create code for each substring by using array for each alphabet.

   converting that code to string and map that string using hashmap.

   increment result if a substring's map value contains non zero value.

My code:

```
 static int sherlockAndAnagrams(String s) {
 HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
 int d,i,k=0;
 int length = s.length();
 int n = length*(length+1)/2;
 String []sub = new String[n]; 
 for (d = 0; d < length; d++){
     for(i = d+1; i <= length; i++)
      {
        sub[k++] = s.substring(d, i);
      }
  }
int []c = new int[26];

  int result=0;;
for(int l=0;l<n;l++){
    for(int m=0;m<25;m++){
    c[m] = 0;
    }
   char []suba = sub[l].toCharArray();  
  for(char ch : suba){
      c[ch-'a']+=1;
  }
  String temp = Arrays.toString(c);
  Integer x = map.get(temp);
  if(x!=null){
      result = result+x;
    map.put(temp,++x);}
  else{
  map.put(temp,1);
   }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Please do not include a picture where text would be better. Paraphrase the problem and example text.

Comment: @NomadMaker Actually I included the initial picture because otherwise we would have to format a lot.

Comment: @ankit715 You have to count pairs and not how many collide. Also, map.put(...,x++) should be map.put(...,++x);

Comment: @vivek_23 "Formatting a lot" is not an excuse to include pictures. The rule is if it can be written, write it.

Comment: @vivek_23 yes it worked! But still 2 out of 7 test cases failed.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Ok, will take care next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so a couple of things here.

- You have to count pairs and not how many collide.
- So, it would be `result = result + x;`
- Also, `map.put(...,x++)` should be `map.put(...,++x);` as we are going to update with a pre-incremented value.
- Also, your filling of `c` goes from `0` to `24` but it should be `0` to `25`. It's a better practice to just do `Arrays.fill(c,0)` for that matter.

---

For space efficiency, we can completely avoid taking each subarray in an array and rather just sort the subarray based on characters. This way, every anagram will map to the same key in the map, helping you to avoid storing each array explicitly in the `sub` string array. However, the overall space complexity would remain the same.

Comment: please elaborate on "sort the subarray based on characters".

Comment: @ankit715 Like say you have 2 substrings `eat` and `tea`. If you sort by characters, you would have `aet` and `aet` for both, indicating that they both are anagrams

Comment: @nice_dev 4th point , Filling of c should be 0 to 26 and not 0 to 25 or Arrays.fill(c,0) will also do the trick.

Comment: @jack_07 I meant <= 25.